# Vite is not transpiling ES6 syntax

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vite

I'm setting up a new repo to transpile a bunch of HTML, CSS and JS into modules that can be imported in my projects. However, I can't seem to transpile the JS file properly i.e. the output script does not contain the JavaScript code I've written.

This is my Vite config(disabling minify temporarily to show readable content):

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { resolve } from 'path'

import { ViteMinifyPlugin } from 'vite-plugin-minify'

export default defineConfig({
  copyPublicDir: false,
  build: {
    minify: false,
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        footer: resolve(__dirname, 'src/footer/footer.html'),
        navbar: resolve(__dirname, 'src/navbar/navbar.html'),
      },
      output: {
        entryFileNames: `assets/[name].js`,
        chunkFileNames: `assets/[name].js`,
        assetFileNames: `assets/[name].[ext]`
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    // ViteMinifyPlugin({})
  ]
})
```

This is JavaScript code I use for testing purpose:

```js
function loadUserInfo() {
  return {
    email: "janedoe@abc.com",
    name: "Jane Doe",
    username: "janedoe"
  }
}

const world = "hello world"

console.log("testing")

export { loadUserInfo, world }
```

and this is the transpiled JavaScript code:

```
(function polyfill() {
  const relList = document.createElement("link").relList;
  if (relList && relList.supports && relList.supports("modulepreload")) {
    return;
  }
  for (const link of document.querySelectorAll('link[rel="modulepreload"]')) {
    processPreload(link);
  }
  new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
    for (const mutation of mutations) {
      if (mutation.type !== "childList") {
        continue;
      }
      for (const node of mutation.addedNodes) {
        if (node.tagName === "LINK" && node.rel === "modulepreload")
          processPreload(node);
      }
    }
  }).observe(document, { childList: true, subtree: true });
  function getFetchOpts(link) {
    const fetchOpts = {};
    if (link.integrity)
      fetchOpts.integrity = link.integrity;
    if (link.referrerPolicy)
      fetchOpts.referrerPolicy = link.referrerPolicy;
    if (link.crossOrigin === "use-credentials")
      fetchOpts.credentials = "include";
    else if (link.crossOrigin === "anonymous")
      fetchOpts.credentials = "omit";
    else
      fetchOpts.credentials = "same-origin";
    return fetchOpts;
  }
  function processPreload(link) {
    if (link.ep)
      return;
    link.ep = true;
    const fetchOpts = getFetchOpts(link);
    fetch(link.href, fetchOpts);
  }
})();
console.log("testing");
```

As you can see, only `console.log("testing")` is being parsed to the generated script. What am I missing here?

Updated:

Disabling tree shaking works without modification but somehow stopped working once I re-enable minification:

```js
(function(){const t=document.createElement("link").relList;if(t&&t.supports&&t.supports("modulepreload"))return;for(const e of document.querySelectorAll('link[rel="modulepreload"]'))n(e);new MutationObserver(e=>{for(const r of e)if(r.type==="childList")for(const o of r.addedNodes)o.tagName==="LINK"&&o.rel==="modulepreload"&&n(o)}).observe(document,{childList:!0,subtree:!0});function s(e){const r={};return e.integrity&&(r.integrity=e.integrity),e.referrerPolicy&&(r.referrerPolicy=e.referrerPolicy),e.crossOrigin==="use-credentials"?r.credentials="include":e.crossOrigin==="anonymous"?r.credentials="omit":r.credentials="same-origin",r}function n(e){if(e.ep)return;e.ep=!0;const r=s(e);fetch(e.href,r)}})();console.log("testing");
```

Comment: If the code isn’t used anywhere it’s probably doing tree shaking. Disable that in rollupOptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Vite tells rollup to do tree shaking which means it will remove all unused code. If you want to keep all code even if it’s not used you can add `treeshake: false` to `rollupOptions`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! It was working at first but somehow after re-enabling the minification, the code isn't transpiled again. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I've updated the original post to show you the minified JavaScript file

Comment: Update: I have to configure `terser` to further ignoring dead code but your solution works.